# Weird behaviour of sum in ruby on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Have anyone noticed something like this? Why is it happening?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > User.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" 
 => 102 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > User.count + 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" 
 => 103 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :008 > User.count+ 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" 
 => 103 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 > User.count+1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" 
 => 103 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010 > User.count +1
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM "users" 
 => 102
```

Using `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]` && `Rails 3.1.3`

Extra stuff:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > "ayay".length + 1
 => 5 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :008 > "ayay".length +1
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
    from (irb):8:in `length'
    ...
```

Comment: Weird. And "(User.count) +1" returns "103". Btw, it's reproducible in ruby 1.8.7/rails 2.3.8 and even in jruby/rails 3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the fact that in Ruby white spaces **can be** significant. You see different results because Ruby interprets your example in different ways. So

The first:

```
"ayay".length + 1
```

is like

```
"ayay".length.+(1)
```

And the second:

```
"ayay".length +1
```

is like

```
 "ayay".length(+1)
```

In this way you can *see* why Ruby gives an error in the second case.

Regarding the [count](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/count) problem: Ruby interprets the code as:

```
User.count(+1)
```

And, as you can see from the generated SQL, there is a difference because `+1` is considered the column_name parameter.

Comment: Parentheses often can save you :)

Comment: Thank you for the response, just what I thought. Nonetheless, seems a strange behaviour...